# How do I copy the value of an object between domains using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to copy the value of an element between two different domains using Cypress.

However, Cypress does not allow me to visit two different domains within the same test and I am unsure on how to copy the value to another test.

My code looks as follows:

```
  it('Gets MFA Token', () => {

//define String
var password = 'Password';

//Encode the String
var encodedString = btoa(password);
console.log(encodedString); // Outputs: "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"

// Decode the String
var decodedString = atob(encodedString);
console.log(decodedString); // Outputs: "Password"

// Visit token retrieval page
cy.visit('https://totp.danhersam.com')

// Fill in token secret
cy.get('#app > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > input').type('TOKENTHINGYVALUE')

// Retrieve mfa token
cy.get('#app > div > div.box > p').then(($token) => {

// Store the token's text
const mfatoken = $token.text()

 })
})

it('Uses MFA Token', () => {

// Visit MFA login page
cy.visit('https://mydomain/mfa_test.html')

// Fill in credentials
cy.get('#uid').type('username')
cy.get('#password').type(password)
cy.get('#form > div:nth-child(7) > div > div > input').click()

// Fill in mfatoken
cy.get('#otppswd').type(mfatoken)
cy.get('#main > div > div > form > div.section > div > input').click()

   })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way.

I solved it as follows:

Within the first test where I retrieve the MFA Token in my case I use the .as function that comes with Cypress (see their Aliasses documentation)

```
// Retrieve mfa token
cy.get('#app > div > div.box > p').as('mfatoken')
```

In the next test where I wish to use this token again I call it as follows.

```
// Fill in mfatoken
cy.get('#otppswd').type('@mfatoken')
```

Please note the @ symbol, this calls the variable saved using the .as function.
Which can be used across tests.